# Запрет выбора значения выпадающего списка при невыполнении условий

Tags: google-spreadsheet

штатными средствами (формулы, зависимые списки и пр.) не справился, чувствую, нужен скрипт))
дано: столбец с выпадающим списком, 5 значений, соседний столбец со значением в двух вариантах 0 или больше 0
задача: запретить выбор последнего из значений выпадающего списка и выдать предупреждение пользователю о запрете ввода, если значение соседней ячейки больше 0

Comment: Покажите живой пример, чего-нибудь придумаем

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AyeL3rmGpdsy0m1Aaiqg7XZf3DXD3S-PprbruYTRS9M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: речь о столбцах K - L

Comment: Нет доступа, только просмотр... Запретить выбор без скриптов не получится. Но есть идея - условное форматирование ячейки (например, красный цвет)

Comment: Пардон, поправил доступ)

Comment: Цветовое выделение - не вариант, особо одаренные сотрудники просто плюнут и пойдут дальше